# Defining a method to be used with view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on ROR app. The thing i need is a simple slider for view and whenever user change slider i want a method to be call with argument as the value in the slider.

My question:
1) How to call a method every time user change slider.
2) Which is the best place to define method i.e in which file controller class or somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

A slider would be a JavaScript thing. So you'd have JavaScript events listening for slider changes, and then pulling out whatever attributes you need from that event. Hopefully you could reuse a slider plugin which would almost certainly provide such an event hook for you. Check out: http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/tools/awesome-jquery-sliders/.

If you're saying that after the JavaScript event you'd like to pass the slider state back to your server... then you'd need to make an AJAX call. For this, create a controller that makes sense for receiving this call and point the AJAX code to an action in this controller. The controller can then do whatever you want with the value: store it in the database or whatever.